# MongoDB finding all sub-nodes

Tags: mongodb

I have categories collection with documents related to each other in a tree structure just as the simplified version shown below:

```
  {
    categoryID: "ABC",
    parentID: "AB"
  }

  {
    categoryID: "ABD",
    parentID: "AB"
  }

  {
    categoryID: "ABD1",
    parentID: "ABD"
  }
```

so that the resulting tree will be something like:

```
- A
--- AA
------AAA
------AAB
------AAC
--- AB
------ABA
----------ABAA
----------ABAB
--------------ABABA
--------------ABABB
------ABB
```

Is it possible to find / return all categories under AB, in other words so that the result will include only the following categories (based on the example shown above)? Thanks

```
- ABA
- ABAA
- ABAB
- ABABA
- ABABB
- ABB
```

Comment: Two comments: 1) Where's your code so far? 2) Hint: Recursion might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation has [an entire section on representing tree structures](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/). Essentially, if you want subtree queries fast, store the [list of all ancestors for a node](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/) and use a multikey index, e.g.

```
{
  categoryID: "ABD1",
  parentID: "ABD",
  ancestors: ["ABD", "AB", "A"] // multikey index
}
```

Then query `db.categories.find({"ancestors" : "AB"});`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Ancestors approach will solve the problem either in finding ancestors of any node (category) or for finding children (descendants) of any node.